# Intersection of a Ray and an Elliptic Paraboloid

Tags: linear-algebra

given a line equation as

$$\overrightarrow{r} = (2, 1, 0)^T + \lambda * (0, 0, -1)^T$$

and a elliptic paraboloid as

$$P = \{ (x, y, z)^T \in R^3  | z = x^2 + y^2 \}$$

I want to compute the first intersection point of the ray with the surface of the paraboloid. My first idea was to define the quadric matrix of the paraboloid with

$$ Q = \left( \begin{array}{rrr}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}\right)$$

such that we get the intersection points with $$r^T * Q * r = 0$$

But with this equation, I will divide by zero by computing each $\lambda$. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: First? Note that the ray is vertical, and parallel to the axis of the paraboloid. You know $x=2,y=1$ for any point on the ray. It should not be too difficilt to find $z$.

Comment: ah yes it's really easy...don't know why I had so much problems with it